# Use iptables to block local connection

Tags: firewall, iptables

I wish to block all connections (local and remote) to a service running on a particular port, say port 1000.

I have tried the following command:

`iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp  --dport 9999 -j DROP`

both with and without `-i lo`, but I can still connect to the service using

`nc localhost 9999`.

---

Result of `iptables --list`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9999
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: what does this say?  iptables --list INPUT

Comment: Blocking *lo* is a truly terrible idea. *lo* is used in Nix for interprocess communication, it is best just left alone.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: I do, in fact, wish to prevent unpriviledged processes from communicating with this one. I intend to force all communication with this process over a unix socket.

Comment: On Line 2 you accept all anywhere after that the rest of your rules are ignored in the input chain.  RELATED,ESTABLISHED should be 1st in the input chain.

Answer (score 1):

going from 127.0.0.1 to whatever goes through FORWARD

Locally you may have to add:

iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1000 -j DROP

Comment: Doesn't work :(.

Comment: @SamirJindel  Obviously we need to see **iptables --list**

Comment: Note: If you block port 80 for www, apache will still start, but you won't be able to communicate with it.

Comment: Try it without the **-m tcp**

Comment: and keep your rule on the INPUT chain at the same time,

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands.

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1000 -j DROP

service iptables save

Check the updates rules using iptables -L

Comment: That's exactly what I already tried... without success.

Comment: Pls  add the same on  /etc/sysconfig/iptables